# DevExpress How to get sum of GridView column's C#

Tags: c#, devexpress

I try to get summary of gridView column's and pass it to textEdit,
I try this code:

```
textedit1.text= Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.Columns[1].SummaryItem.SummaryValue).ToString();
```

but always I get 0 value
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by set `SummaryType` to sum and it works as a charm.

```
gridview1.Columns["salary"].SummaryItem.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum;
```

Or from the designer, select `gridControl`, quick menu, Run Designer:
Columns, Select the required column, from its properties select `SummaryItem` and change `SummaryType` to `sum`.

Comment: How did you set that value?

Answer (score 2):

You must set the GridView.OptionsView.ShowFooter property to true, you will see this summary value within a grid footer.

```
 textedit1.text = gridView1.Columns["Salary"].SummaryItem.SummaryValue.ToString();
```